# Почему не подсвечивает Vue код , много плагинов перепробывал и все ровно(c классической темой тоже)

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

[image: Просто белый текст]

**Почему не подсвечивает Vue код , много плагинов перепробывал и все ровно(c классической темой тоже) просто белой текст**

Comment: Какое расширение файла?

Comment: `Vue Language Features (Volar) v1.8.1` VScode

Comment: Если не решили проблему. Пришлите, пожалуйста, перечень расширений, которые пробовали устанавливать и скриншот установленных.
У меня установлен Vetur и всё отлично работает